# Is there a limit of views in a iphone application?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

The title says everything.

Do I have a limit of views?

Thanks.

Comment: My question was answered correctly, I still didn't understand -8 points...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read some documentation before asking these type of questions.

Any way, the iphone app is not limited by the number of pages/views/controls in it.

But the app is limited by the size of 2GB. And also apps larger than 50MB in size will not download over cellular networks

Comment: why not downloaded the app more than 20MB?

Comment: Be sure to take into account the fact that an iOS device is limited on RAM, and therefore attempting to display an excessive amount of views at any one time will cause memory issues, which may lead to crashing.